# What am I doing wrong with this charge transfer problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge

I am tutoring a student in Physics, and their online homework checker is rejecting our answer to this question. What are we doing wrong?

---

This is the question in its entirety:

Three conductive spheres are held at the end of insulating rods. Sphere A has a charge of +8Q, sphere B has a charge of +3Q, and sphere C has zero charge.

You touch spheres A and B and separate them. Then you touch spheres A and C and separate them. Then you touch spheres B and C and separate them.

What is the final charge on sphere C? What is the total charge before they touch? What is the total charge after they touch?

There is no mention of the spheres having different masses or absolute potentials. I arrive on a charge of +4.125Q on sphere C, and a total charge of +11Q both before and after the touching.  Here is my reasoning:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| Stage | Sphere A | Sphere B | Sphere C |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| Start | +8Q      | +3Q      | 0Q       |
| A+B   | +5.5Q    | +5.5Q    | 0Q       |
| A+C   | +2.75Q   | +5.5Q    | +2.75Q   |
| B+C   | +2.75Q   | +4.125Q  | +4.125Q  |
```

Comment: Are all the spheres the same size? Was there any mention of the spheres being charged to the same potential?